# HttpHeaders in Angular being sent as Access-Control-Request-Headers instead of an actual header

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm building my Angular app, I need to pass some stuff in the header, like an auth key.  However, whenever I set the header it does not appear as part of the request.

Here's my code

```
getSomething(){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Admin-Password", "test1234")
    };
    return this.http.get(this.endpoint, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData));
  }
```

And here's the full request is sent

```
OPTIONS /v1/login/admin HTTP/1.1
Host: api.****
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: admin-password
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close
```

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong.

Comment: That's as expected, only a subset of headers is sent on a preflight request. What's the *problem*?

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting CORS error, even though the server has a wildcard for the origin.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]: what's the response to the preflight request; how's the server configured; etc.

Comment: Executing the code from the first post, I'm getting the error in the console log
```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api.***/v1/login/admin' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field auth_token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```
The server is running on Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu).
The expected response is the body with an authkey.

Comment: Why have you only just mentioned that? What you've shown isn't setting that header, so it's hard to say; again, we need enough information to actually recreate the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what else should I post. the function getsomething is called on click, but I don't think that's important for the problem. I tried using a placeholder API and I was getting results correctly.
Please point me in the right direction, where to look

Comment: Well your server seems to be complaining that the request has a header, `auth_token`, that isn't allowed on the preflight OPTIONS request. The code you've shown *doesn't set that header*. So in your position I'd be looking through the codebase in search of something that does, but we can't help you with that.